# Quotient ring of $T/I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please help me to identify the Quotient Ring of $T/I$, since $T$ is set of all triangular matrices, and $I$ is set of all strictly triangular matrices and $I$ is ideal in $T$.

For your help I am really appreciate. thanks

Comment: When you say *the set of all triangular matrices*, are you including both upper and lower triangular, or just one of these?

Comment: @Brian All triangular matrices are including both upper and lower triangular..

Comment: But then $T$ isn’t a ring: it’s not closed under addition.

Comment: okay let we specific only for upper triangular, I think that will be more reliable..

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Every matrix in $T$ can be written uniquely in the form $D+A$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $A\in I$. And the set of diagonal matrices is a ring.

**Added:** Let $T$ be the set of upper triangular $n\times n$ matrices. For each $A=[a_{ij}]\in T$ let $\varphi(A)$ be the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $a_{ii}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Let $D$ be the set of diagonal $n\times n$ matrices. Show that $\varphi:T\to D$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I$.

Comment: can you show the proof clearly, honestly i do not understand how to do that and your HINT about is...

Comment: @mary: I’ve expanded it a bit; I’d rather not say any more until you’ve had a chance to think about it and try to finish it on your own.

Comment: thanks for the guidelines, I am really appreciated...

Comment: @mary: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

@Brian thanks I cited some your hint in this my answer..

Since $I$ is an ideal in $T$, now we can get $T/I \cong R^n$ as a rings. Let $T$ be the set of upper triangular $n \times n$ matrices. For each $A=[a_{ij}] \in T$, $D$ be the set of diagonal $n \times n$ matrices.

Clearly any matrix $T$ can written uniquely in the form $T=A+D$ and $A \in I$.

Then, since $\varphi:T\to D$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I$, the ring of diagonal matrices is isomorphism to $R^n$.

Comment: If I were writing it up as homework, for instance, I’d say a little more about why $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism and why $D\cong\Bbb R^n$, but you have the key pieces.